# Appending HTML and PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How can I append HTML with some PHP code to specified files.
Basically I have a menu/nav and its annoying having to constantly edit each file to add a new tab etc. The nav is responsive so I cant just embed it which I wouldnt do anyway. I need it to do for example Include() but i have a menu.html file trying to do `<?php include 'http://www.example.com/menu.html'; ?>` in my index.php file where it should show the Menu but it show up.

Ive also tried Include(menu.html); but that wont work as my index.php where im trying to include() the menu in is in a different directory to the menu.

Is there any way I can basically import HTML to a bunch of pages? If possible when its importing to the pages all the pages should have the exact same HTML menu whenever I edit the menu.html. There should also be only 1 menu.html which is the main reason im doing this so I lighten up file space and take less time editing the menus.

Comment: you can include the file but you need to use a `absolute` path on your server `/home/website/menu.html` not `http://`

Comment: use `../path_to_menu/menu.html`. `../` will is used to move to the parent directory where your file is currently present

Comment: do you mean /public_html/menu.html then cmorrissey?

Comment: I have tried <?php include('/public_html/menu.php'); ?> but its not working I have also tried <?php include('../../../menu.php'); ?> Just to say the index.php is in for example publichtml/folder1/folder2/folder3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you change the menu.html to be menu.php, define your HTML menu in function?

For example

In menu.php

```
function menu(){
    echo "<div>Your menu code in here</div>";
}
```

In index.php

```
include("menu.php");
//here where you place your menu
menu();
```

Comment: You know you can `include` any file, right? Doesn't have to be PHP.

Comment: You can even have plain HTML in your `menu.php` file and then include is as usual. No need to do a function and print the menu by echoing a string.

Comment: dis works but whe i put the 20 line+ code of the menu it lags the page so much and loads almost nothing

Comment: but guys im having an issue when i put my proxy scraper PHP in the index.php for some reason its interfering with the Menu not allowing JS stuff to work like dropdowns and hover stuff why?

Comment: But if you don't put it in the function, how could you make sure you print the menu at the correct location? or you put the include at the place you want to have that menu?

Comment: gie3d the Include tag auto adds it wherever you put it so having menu() makes no sense but thx your answer and taking off the echo and php tags solved it

Comment: but im having issues with the menu its getting interfered with some php i have. Ill make a new question

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).
Use it as below:

```
     $menu = file_get_contents(path/to/menu.html);
```

and then `echo $menu;` at the place u need in the page to be loaded in this case index.php

Comment: `readfile` and `include` are both better options than `echo file_get_contents` - especially if the included file is quite large.

Comment: file_get_contents supports url to a file i.e, why I suugested as OP is using a url in the question

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `include()` or `require()` should be used to do this.

What you need to know about these functions though is that they include a file from the filesystem and not a URL.

So your usage basically should be like `include('/path/to/file.html');`

These functions are basically used everywhere when you want to scale up your application and have reusable blocks of code like functions and classes.

Another variation for both these functions is `include_once()` and `require_once` which will only include the file once if you try to include it again.

Answer (score 0):

It would be beneficial for you to read up on PHP templating, something like this should help get you started: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-templating.html

Comment: Link-only answers are bad in general, but this one... I'm not sure I'm seeing the relevance here.

Comment: The OP is obviously new to PHP templating. I cannot write a whole guide within an SO answer. Sometimes people need to read a decent tutorial/manual rather than picking up little bits of information here there and everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

While the "correct" way to do it is to specify an `include_path`, my personal preference is to start my init script with:

```
chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

This means I can now call `include` or `require` - or any file operation really - and specify a path starting from the root of the site, without having to worry about if I'm already in a subfolder when I do it.

Depending on the organisation of your code, you may want a different base path.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you need to add menu/navigation file to pages. I do have some solutions as follows.

1. Firstly, you need to create .php file and include html code in it.
2. Secondly, if you are using any framework or cms then please include it in header.
3. At last, if you are using core php then follow step 1.

Alternately, if you want different menu on different pages then  you need to handle it with some checks